# How to scroll through PDF opened in embed tag in chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf

After clicking on a link it opens up PDF in a new tab in chrome. The PDF can contains more than one page. The PDF is inside an `<embed>` tag . What I want to achieve is by using either javascript or jQuery to be able to scroll the PDF in developer's tool console of chrome browser. When I click right on page, I can't see the source code.

I tried using

```
window.scrollBy(0,200)
window.scrollTo(0,200)
```

but javascript doesn't seem to work.
The source of the pdf is something like below

```
<html>
<BODY>
<EMBED ID='ID' SRC='URL.PDF' TYPE='application/pdf' internalinstanceid='5'></EMBED>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Is there any other method or way through which I can achieve to scrolling through the PDF? Is there any command which I can enter in chrome's developer console which will scroll through PDF?

Answer (score 3):

In short you can't - A PDF is not a DOM element it is a document that is rendered  by a special PDF reader in the browser. Each browser has its own mechanism for rendering PDFs and there is no way to programmatically control them like you want.

At best you can skip pages like using something like so (presuming your embed is the first on the page)

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName('embed')[0]
x.src = "url/to/your.pdf?page=page_number"
```

This will cause the embedded PDF to navigate to `page_number`

Edit:

You could (theoretically) achieve this if you could use an old browser that still has support for an NPAPI PDF plugin - then you could simulate arrow key presses that would allow you to scroll through the document. However in all modern browsers this isn't possible as you can't trigger keyevents without some kind of user interaction (for really good reasons!).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So there is no way i can programmatically scroll the PDF that is opened in the browser? And the thing is the URL keep dynamically changing on each click. If i use the same URL to reload the PDF again it gives -404 error.

Comment: Not really - I guess It really would depend on *how* it is opened and which browser - you may be able to use something like PDF.js to achieve this but I doubt it.

Answer (score 2):

While at the moment you cannot make a cross browser solution, because how pdfs are rendered is not part of a standard, chromium based browsers (chrome, edge, opera, etc.) wrap the pdf displaying plugin with elements that enable some interaction with it using the DOM.

Around the embed tag you found chrome builds some divs using a web-component for the GUI including the scrollbar! And guess what happens when you scroll this container?

```
let scroller = document.getElementsByTagName('pdf-viewer')[0].shadowRoot.getElementById('scroller')
scroller.scrollBy(0,200)
```

I suspect this is part of Chromes Initiative to explain browser behavior that was part of the web-component move