# How to programatically scroll in a WebView2?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, webview, webview2

I've recently started a WPF project that uses a Microsoft.Web.WebView2 to display a PDF file. I want to be able to scroll through the PDF file programmatically.

I have tried this: `browser.ExecuteScriptAsync("window.scrollTo(0,300);");` to scroll down to 300px but nothing seems to happen. What am I doing wrong ? Is there a better/simpler way of achieving what I want ?

Thanks

Comment: Use window.scroll, instead of window.scrollTo"

Comment: @Frenchy still doesn't work... `private async void scrollWebView(int yScrollPixelAmount)
        {
            await browser.ExecuteScriptAsync($"window.scroll(0,{yScrollPixelAmount});");
        }`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to scroll through PDF opened in embed tag in chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49295986/how-to-scroll-through-pdf-opened-in-embed-tag-in-chrome)